# How to check if files matching a regex exist in a directory in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like some help in finding a way to check if files matching a certain regex exist in a directory. Currently, I am using the following method, but it will return an error in certain cases:

```
ls srv_*.log
```

The above command will result in **ls: cannot access srv_*.log: No such file or directory** if there are no files in the directory matching the regex.

The regex I am trying to match is **"srv_*.log"**

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`srv_*.log` is not a regex but a glob matcher.

You can just capture the output and redirect stderr to /dev/null:

```
FILES_LIST="$(ls srv_*.log 2>/dev/null)"
for file in $FILES_LIST; do
    #something with $file
done
```

And you could even do without `FILES_LIST` here.

Comment: Hi fge, could you please explain the "2>/dev/null" and how it works? Thanks.

Comment: It discards stderror, though you really don't need to run `ls` for this purpose in bash. And actually it will not work if you happen to have files with spaces in them.

Comment: It redirects stderr to /dev/null. You must first understand that even with your first command, it would have worked: `ls` puts its result to stdout by default, and it outputs only errors to stderr.  If you do `A=$(ls nonexistingfile); echo $A` you will see that the echo returns nothing, whether you add `2>/dev/null` to the substitution or not.

Answer (score 5):

Use [find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)

A simple example,

```
find $DIR -type f -name "srv_*.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

From `bash` manpage:

> If the **nullglob** option is set, and no matches are found, the word is
>   removed.  If  the  **failglob** shell option is set, and no matches are
>   found, an error message is printed and the command is not executed.

meaning you may want to

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in the good directory, you can do :

```
shopt -s nullglob
set -- srv_*.log
if [ $# -gt 0 ]
then
  #do your stuff
fi
```

`$#` contains the number of matching files

Answer (score 0):

Bash has a built-in command for that:

```
compgen -G [GLOB]
```